# Vite: Get URL for separate module bundle so that it can be dynamically imported by a Worker

Tags: vite, web-worker

### Question

I am creating a library that runs mainly in Web Worker (although it can also be run in the Main thread as well). I want the app that is using my library (let's assume they build their app with Vite) to be able to create a custom bundle of code that is separate from their main app bundle. The app should be able to get the URL of this custom bundle of code in some programmatic way and then pass it to the Web Worker (via the library API). The Web Worker then dynamically imports that bundle.

Essentially I need a nice way to allow an application to inject custom code into my library's Web Worker. Is there a supported way to facilitate this with Vite?

### Hacky Dev Mode Only Solution

I discovered a somewhat hacky way to do it but it only really works in dev mode when running `vite`. This uses Vite's [Web Worker API](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#web-workers) both in the way it was intended (to import a Web Worker), and in a way it is not (to both generate and get the URL of a separate non-Web Worker bundle).

**App's index.ts file**

```
// Import the library's worker itself with Vite's Web Worker import API
import LibraryWorker from '../library/LibraryWorker.js?worker';

// Use the same Web Worker import API but in URL mode
// This tell's Vite to create a separate bundle for CustomCodeModule.js
// but only return the URL to that bundle
import customModuleBundleUrl from './CustomCodeModule.js?worker&url';

(async () => {
  console.log('customModuleBundle', customModuleBundleUrl);
  // Start the worker
  const worker = new LibraryWorker();
  // Wait some time for worker to be ready
  await sleep(1000);
  // Send the custom module bundle to the Worker
  worker.postMessage({
    type: 'init',
    url: customModuleBundleUrl,
  });
})();

function sleep(ms: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

**Library's LibraryWorker.ts**

```
// Listen for the `init` message
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data.type === 'init') {
    // Dynamically import the custom bundle URL
    import(event.data.url /* @vite-ignore */).then(({ CustomCode }) => {
      // Execute the module exported by the custom bundle
      const customCode = new CustomCode();
      customCode.run();
    });
  }
});
```

**App's CustomCodeModule.js**

```
export class CustomCode {
  constructor() {}

  run() {
    console.log("CustomCode from the App running in the Library's worker!");
  }
}
```

Here's a [StackBlitz Running Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-c7wef2) you can play with.

#### Production Build Problems

If I try the same example by building a production build with `vite build` and then `vite preview` to serve that production build here's what happens:

1. Vite removes all of the `exports` from the CustomCodeModule in its bundle.
2. Since nothing is exported in the bundle and none of the code is actually executed in the bundle, Vite tree shakes it away completely.

I presume it does these two things because in the context of a Web Worker you would not have any exports. But funny how it still works in dev mode.

Does anyone know if there's a proper way to do this with Vite? It seems like the Web Worker API URL feature is just 1 step away from what I need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to import a script directly as a worker in Vite. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets#importing-script-as-a-worker and https://vitejs.dev/guide/features#import-with-query-suffixes

```js
// Separate chunk in the production build
import Worker from './shader.js?worker'
const worker = new Worker()

// sharedworker
import SharedWorker from './shader.js?sharedworker'
const sharedWorker = new SharedWorker()

// Inlined as base64 strings
import InlineWorker from './shader.js?worker&inline'
```

If you need the URL as a string (because an external library such as `pdfjs` manages the worker internally and just want the URL) you can import it as such:

```js
import MyWorker from './worker?worker&url'
```